# removing characters from a string in a specific column

Tags: string, printing

I have a text file where the barcode is in column 18. I'm interested in removing the last 16 characters from a TCGA barcode for a long list of samples or alternatively I want to print only the first 12 characters in the string from column 18 to a new column

For example: 
TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A-11D-A403-09  needs to be shorted to TCGA-2E-A9G8 and print the shorted ID in a new column

I've seen responses such as:  echo "${string:0:-16}"
I'm very new to programing so i'm not sure how to automate this for a spreadsheet with over 300,000 lines and directed to a specific column

Comment: can you show a sample of your text file. this can be done easily in notepad++ if its a csv file.

Comment: Its a MAF file downloaded from TCGA/GDC.

Comment: i'm not sure how to attach an entire file here?

Comment: It looks like its just a tab delimited file. open it up with a text editor and extract a few lines from it.

Comment: Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id Center NCBI_Build Chromosome Start_position End_position Strand Variant_Classification Variant_Type Reference_Allele Tumor_Seq_Allele1 Tumor_Seq_Allele2 dbSNP_RS dbSNP_Val_Status Tumor_Sample_Barcode
AF121898.3 0 broad.mit.edu 37 8 88613386 88613386 + RNA DEL T T -   TCGA-2E-A9G8-01A-11D-A403-09

Answer (score 0):

With the example you given above i did this in notepad++
basically it appends the truncated value at the end of the line.
[image]